# approaching points on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider a fixed interval $M$. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we choose $n$ points in M.

(NB: the choosing process is separate, does NOT have to be adding one new point each time)

Since the total number of chosen points are countable, we know that there is a dense set $M'\subset M$ s.t. $M'$ consists of all points that are not chosen for any $n$.

For each point $a\in M'$, let the nearest distance of the nearest point among the $n$ chosen points to $a$ be $D_a(n)$. It is given that $\frac{1}{D_a(n)}$ is of the order $O(exp(C_{a}n))$ for some $C_a$ only depending on $a$.

Proof or refute: *the nearest distance between two of the $n$ chosen points cannot decrease faster than exponentially.
i.e. Let this nearest distance be $d(n)$, then $\frac{1}{d(n)}$ is of the order $O(exp(Cn))$ for some fixed $C$.*

The argument looks suspicious to me, but I haven't been able to figure out a counterexample.

Comment: Maybe that is not your question, but if you take $M=[0,1]$ and repeatedly add points $x_n=\frac1{n!},$ then $d(n)\le d(0, x_n)=\frac1{n!}$

Comment: that doesn't meet the condition for D(n).

Comment: It does for $D_0(n).$

Comment: It seems that the idea by @Invisible works. To make it more precise let for each natural $n$ the set $S_n$ of the chosen points. Put $S_1=\{0\}$ and for each natural $n\ge 2$ let $S_n=S_{n-1}\cup\{1/(n-1)!\}$. Then $1/d(n)=(n-1)!$. Now let $M'$ be any dense set of $M\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} S_n$ and $a\in M'$ be any point. Since $a\ne 0$ then $D_a(n)$ eventually stabilizes at some nonzero constant.

Comment: ok, that works. What if we give a stronger condition that the restriction on $D_a(n)$ holds for all points on $M$? Do we still get a counterexample? @AlexRavsky

Comment: It seems so. The idea is to put $S_0=\varnothing$ and for each natural $n$ put $S_{2n}=S_{2n-2}\cup\{1/2n,1/2n+1/(2n)!\}$.

Comment: So I think you have made a counter example --  Say if $S_1=\{0\}$ and $S_n=S_{n-1} \cup \{ 1/n! \}$. The situation might change if $D_a(n) = \min \{ |a-x| : x\in S_n, x\neq a\}$ excludes $a$ and the condition on $D_a$ is required for *all* $a\in M$